# HTML form in Liferay

Tags: php, forms, liferay

I have made a simple HTML form in Liferay. When the form is submitted, its content should go to my email address and a line saying 'thank you' is to be displayed. I have done the action part with php. But after submitting, all I get is the 'thank you' part and the form doesn't get submitted to my email address.

Any idea why this doesn't work? I am not good with PHP at all. Only the basics.

Is there any other way to do this? e.g with javascript? though that might not be a good option.

I am using Liferay 6.1 and Tomcat 7.

HTML form:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="form.php">
<table>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>
  <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // Email where form is sent:
    $email_to = "myemail@mydomain.com";


Thank you!

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: Tomcat is an implementation of the Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages technologies. Liferay appears to be written in Java. As far as I know, you can't run PHP via Tomcat (unless you have some sort of proxy) … so why are you looking at PHP?

Comment: whether your web server running `PHP`? because Liferay 6.1 and Tomcat 7 are used for `JAVA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer with JSP, which I haven't used since school days. Here is the code in case someone wanted to try it.

```
<%@ page import="sun.net.smtp.SmtpClient, java.io.*, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext,java.util.*" %>
<%
 String from= request.getParameter("from");
 String to= request.getParameter("to");

 try{
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mysitedomain.com");
     client.from(from);
     client.to(to);
     PrintStream message = client.startMessage();
     message.println("From: " + from);
     message.println("To: " + to);
     message.println();
     Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
     while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
       String paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
       String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
       message.println(paramName + ":" + paramValue);
      }
     client.closeServer();
  }
  catch (IOException e){    
     System.out.println("ERROR IN DELIVERING THE FORM:"+e);
  }
 response.sendRedirect("thanks.htm");
%>
```

Comment: Actaully these is one more thing I want to do about that, but couldn't get it wokring. Basically that prints all the inputs, but what I want is to leave out all the empty inputs when delivering the form to my email. Something like this: if (paramValue != null) {message.println(paramName + ":" + paramValue); } but doesn't work yet; so if anyone knows how to do that, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay is able to use PHP Portlets, but you will have to do some configurating, maybe this link can help your case: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/PHP+Portlets

Comment: Thanks Matthias for the link; I will see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with php portlets in version 6.2 for $_POST params. The solution was to put the portlet prefix in the parameter this way

`<input name="_SamplePHP_WAR_samplephpportlet_foo" type="text" />`

that wil make $_POST['foo'] have a parameter